# Define UiApp Variable Globally? - Efficiency (Google Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have 8 or so different .gs files making up GAS for a "Google Sheet"

What I have been wondering is that I have probably 50-100 or so different functions within these different .gs files.

It seems to be a lot easier to define UiApp as Global Scoped.  So the very first 2 lines of my code are:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
myapp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('HMC UI Demo').setHeight(600).setWidth(950);
```

How much difference between defining 'myapp' once in global scope opposed to defining

```
var myapp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('HMC UI Demo').setHeight(600).setWidth(950);
```

within the main doGet function and then

```
var myapp = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
```

within  each individual function.

I'm just wondering because I rarely see any examples where it is not defined within each individual function, however most of these examples are only consisting of a couple functions.

Any help would be appreciated, I've never written anything like this in a scripting language and am finding that one of my main hindrances is the speed of execution.  My user-interface runs too slowly, which in turn makes testing any changes rather time-consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go ahead and define it globally (it's what I do). The time to run those two lines is minimal and prevents code duplication. That also saves me the trouble of passing around those variables when I call functions.

If you need to change the title in the future, you won't have to hunt all over those files for `HMC UI Demo`.

Edit: I actually only write `var app;` in the global scope. I then use `app = UiApp.createApplication();` in my `doGet(e)` function. In server handlers, I'll use `app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();`. I might overuse global variables, but it makes configuration changes much easier.

Comment: You're using `createApplication()` in global or `getActiveApplication()`?

Comment: I'm using createApplication()

Answer (score 0):

I think GAS runs slow regardless of how large your program is. For my apps script, I need to have my UiApp locally scoped, since I am creating multiple GUI's.

If you only have one GUI (and you think it will stay that way) then Globally define it.

Otherwise, if you think you'll be creating other boxes (perhaps another Dialog or Console?) then keep everything locally scoped and just return myapp

EDIT: I think Fred has a good point about changing properties of your UiApp

Comment: UiApp always feels slow to me as well. HTML Service is good (especially in Native mode) if you load your UI before loading your data.

Comment: In hindsight I have been thinking I would have been better off utilizing HTML Service as opposed to Ui.  I haven't really decided yet if I will need to any additional I/O boxes.       But you did bring up a good point in that I have 5 additional spreadsheets that serve as the source data and eventually when it is in the end user's hands, they will need the ability to select updated source files.  Currently, the app accesses these other spreadsheets via their respective IDs defined as object properties.    I've been thinking that I'd use the fileUpload class to provide the desired functionality